# Nav color issue

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I am having an issue with a template that I am trying to adjust to suit my needs. The problem is I am not sure if my issue is with js or css...
I am trying to change the color on the nav when you mouse over (text color change) or go into and sub menu (background color change). The template is using a plugin called hoverIntent.js, and css. Between the two I cannot find where any type or sort of a:hover color adjustment.
The site is [premium-posts.com](http://premium-posts.com/premium_posts/zeni-files/HTML/index.html)
Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: skin.css lines 18 and 71.

Comment: clearly if you look it is a css3 transition, you should watch all css rules, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over one of your nav elements while inspect element is open, you'll see where the color is coming from: skin.css:18.

Comment: Much thanks to all of you who answered. All this is relatively new to me so the guidance is appreciated and I have learned something new.